# Move element to last index of array, multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple loop on an array to produce a new array called dataBlock:

```
$dataBlock = [];

    foreach($root as $data){
        if (array_key_exists($this->number, $root)) {
            $dataBlock = $root[$this->number];
        }
    } 

dd($dataBlock);
```

The dump produces this:

```
array:[
    "abc"=>array:[]
    "total"=>array:[]
    "def"=>array:[]
]
```

But I want total at the bottom like this:

```
array:[
    "abc"=>array:[]
    "def"=>array:[]
    "total"=>array:[]
]
```

How can I properly move the 'total' element to the last index of the array?

Comment: [ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php): Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations. This is useful mainly for associative arrays.  (alo look at the examples on that page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to copy the `total` element, unset it, and then add it back again, which will automatically add it to the end of the array:

```
$data = array(
    'abc' => array(4, 5, 6),
    'total' => array(7, 8, 9),
    'def' => array(3, 4, 5)
    );
    
$total = $data['total'];
unset($data['total']);
$data['total'] = $total;
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [abc] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )
    [def] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
        )
    [total] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )
)
```